# SQLLDR load file with single column

Tags: sql-loader

First time using sqlldr, simply trying to load a file with single column, and cannot find a proper way to do it :(
What do I put as a delimiter?

Here's my .ctl file :

```
load data
 infile 'myfile.dat'
 into table mytable
 fields terminated by ''
 (mycolumn)
```

I keep getting errors in the .log like :

```
Record 4: Rejected - Error on table ..., column ....
ORA-12899: value too large for column "... (actual: 80, maximum: 24)
```

Even though the values in the file are max 8 chars each or smth :
string1
string2
string3

Any help will be much appreciated.

Many thanks,
G

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the `fields terminated by` line in this case but you should have a `TRUNCATE` or `APPEND` depending on if you want to keep existing data or not.

```
load data
infile 'myfile.dat'
truncate
into table mytable
(mycolumn)
```

Comment: Thanks Gary, however with your solution I only get 1 char inserted for each value..
The source column is VARCHAR2(24).
The file is spooled like :
`SET echo off
SET feedback off
SET term off
SET pagesize 0
SET newpage 0
SET space 0
spool myfile.dat
select distinct(mycolumn)from mytable ; 
SPOOL OFF
`
Then before loading the spooled file, the target table is created as : `create table mytable (mycolumn VARCHAR2(24));`  but I still get 1 char inserted from the file..

Comment: actually the issue was in the spooled file, the linefeed was far to the right of each line. It worked when adding `set trimspool on` in the spooling sql

Comment: You could also change the control file to: `mycolumn char "trim(:mycolumn)"`

Answer (score 0):

Why not just change the size of your column to 80 
Alter table  modify  varchar2(80)